# Vue component register warning in unit tests with element-ui

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-component, jestjs

By element-ui documentation, it can be imported "entirely, or just import what you need". I have imported it entirely in application entry point main.js.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'

Vue.use(ElementUI)

const Component = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "component" */ './views/Component.vue')

// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {Component}
})
```

Like that it is possible to use all element-ui components in my custom components. For example I've used [button](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/button) component in Component.vue. That looks fine and button is rendered in App.vue.

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-button>{{ buttonText }}</el-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'component',

    data () {
      return {
        buttonText: 'Button Text'
      }
    },

    components: {}
  }
</script>
```

Now I have created test against this component using vue-jest and @vue/test-utils where I am testing is text in the button is rendered correctly. The test passed but I have Vue warning that button component is not registered:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

This is probably happening because I have imported all element-ui components directly in main.js file (as they propose in documentation) and not in Component.vue. Does anybody know how can I avoid this warning or how can I import component in the test?

Component.spec.js

```
import { shallow } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '../Component.vue'

describe('Component.vue', () => {
  test('sanity test', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })

  test('renders button title', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Component)
    wrapper.setData({buttonText: 'This is text'})
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('This is text')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your tests, create a local Vue, call `.use` in it and pass it to `shallow`:

```js
import { shallow , createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils';   // changed
import Vue from 'vue';                                       // added
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';                          // added
import Component from '../Component.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue();                           // added
localVue.use(ElementUI);                                     // added

describe('Component.vue', () => {
  test('sanity test', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })

  test('renders button title', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Component, {localVue})           // changed
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to import the required module using `Vue.use(Module)` in your *.spec* file.

```
// + Vue.use(ElementUI)

describe('Component.vue', () => {
  ...
})
```

You might get an error stating that you cannot import entire module because `preventFullImport` setting is `true`. To prevent it, modify your [.babelrc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-imports) or equivalent file and change your settings accordingly. All I did was `preventFullImport: false` (personally for test cases only).

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Now I have imported entirely ElementUI in _.spec_ file and there is no more warning, but it is not possible to use ElementUI components in the test. For example if I want to test am I using 3 <el-button> components in _Component.vue_ file, my test should be something like: 

`expect(wrapper.findAll(ElButton)).toEqual(3)`

But in the _.spec_ file ElButton is not defined. Do you know how it can be imported from ElementUI?

Comment: If importing that component directly from `node_elements` didn't help then you could try with `Vue.use(ElementUI, { components: { _componentA_, _componentB_ } })`. I cant seem to point out why you wouldn't be able to see a defined object if you have already imported it.

Answer (score 0):

TESTED

Hello, after many hours of looking I find an another answer, here you dont need to manually set each custom component, as in the first answer.

add a components.js file where you register all of your global vue components:

componentsbind.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
//this are the components I want to import
import MyHeader from '@/components/MyHeader'
import MyNav from '@/components/MyNav'
Vue.component('MyHeader', MyHeader)
Vue.component('MyNav', MyNav)
```

In jest.config.js add

```
modules.exports = {
moduleNameMapper:{
    "~(.*)$": "<rootDir>/resources/js/$1",
},
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>resources/src/tests/setup.js']
}
```

add a setup.js file in test folder

```
import '../componentsbind.js'
```

structure

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    ├── components
    └── tests
       └─ unit
          └─ example.spec.js
       └─ setup.js
    └── etc
└──index.js //here in my case I register all of my global vue components
└──componentsbind.js //that is why I put my components.js file in this place
```

and last run! this works for me!

```
npm run test:unit
```

for more info:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1116